# Expected value of an expression with respect to the vector of parameters

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expectation, means

Let $\mathbf{x}=[x_1, x_2,...,x_n]^T$ be a random vector, whose elements are independent random variables (parameters) $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$. Probability density functions of $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ are given and they are not necessarily the same. Now let $f_1(\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}, f_1(\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R},...,f_m(\mathbf{x})\in\mathbb{R}$ be functions of vector $\mathbf{x}$. Finally, let $g(\mathbf{x})$ be a product of functions $f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}),...,f_m(\mathbf{x})$, i.e. $g(\mathbf{x})=f_2(\mathbf{x})...f_m(\mathbf{x})$.

Is it possible to find the expected value of function $g(\mathbf{x})$ with respect to the vector $\mathbf{x}$? In other words, is it possible to calculate

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\{g(\mathbf{x})\} = \mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\{f_2(\mathbf{x})...f_m(\mathbf{x})\}$ ?

Let me remind you that functions $f_1(\mathbf{x}),f_2(\mathbf{x}),...,f_m(\mathbf{x})$ are in $\mathbb{R}$, they are not vectors, while the expected value should be taken with respect to the vector $\mathbf{x}$. I have never seen something like this, so I wonder if this means that I need to successively find expected value of $g(\mathbf{x})$ with respect to each $x_i, i=1,...,n$, i.e. to calculate something like this

$\mathbb{E}_{\mathbf{x}}\{g(\mathbf{x})\} = \mathbb{E}_{x_n}\{\mathbb{E}_{x_{n-1}}\{\mathbb{E}_{x_{n-2}}\{...g(\mathbf{x})...\}\}\}$ ?

Comment: $$E[g (x_1,x_2,...,x_n)]=\iint ...\int_{-\infty,+\infty} g (u_1,u_2,...,u_n) f_{x_1}(u_1)f_{x_2} (u_2)...f_{x_n}(u_n)du_1du_2...du_n$$

Comment: The functions $f_1(x), f_2(x),...,f_m(x)$ are not probability density functions, but some arbitrary functions.